# How do I use sqlmock to mock a table count query (GORM HasTable) in Go?

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, go, go-gorm, go-sqlmock

I'm using `sqlmock` to unit test a set of Mysql database query handlers written in Go. This works great for standard `SELECT` / `INSERT` queries. For our db healthcheck, I'm using GORM's `DB.Migrator().HasTable()` to make sure a particular table exists in our db. The functionality seems to be working properly, but I'm having difficulty mocking the query that's happening under the hood of `HasTable()`. Does anybody have any advice on how to use `sqlmock` to do this?

`HasTable()` is executing the following query:
`SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '' AND table_name = '[table_name]' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'`

My helper function for the test looks like this:

```
    sqlDB, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    // This is the block I'm not sure about...
    mock.ExpectBegin()
    mock.ExpectQuery(regexp.QuoteMeta("SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '' AND table_name = '[table_name]' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'")).
        WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"count(*)"}).
            AddRow(1))
    mock.ExpectCommit()

    setupSqlMock(sqlDB)
}
```

I've tried every combination of `mock.ExpectExec()`, `mock.ExpectQuery()`, and all of their methods that I can think of. Any ideas?

Comment: did you review examples on https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock/blob/master/examples/basic/basic_test.go ?

Comment: @Orion please share the error that you get while running the test.

Comment: @Orion Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what was mentioned in [this](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock/issues/124) GitHub issue, the following might work for mocking the results of a `count(*)` query:

```golang
dbMock.ExpectQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM `mytable` WHERE mydate <= NOW()").
            WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"count"}).AddRow(5))
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `sqlmock.QueryMatcherEqual` you avoid the `*` parsing problem

```
sqlDB, mock, err := sqlmock.New(sqlmock.QueryMatcherOption(sqlmock.QueryMatcherEqual))
```